# Getting a firebase object's key after it has been passed down as a prop in Vue

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Firebase. I have a `thought` schema in the firebase database like this:

```
{
  title: "I should learn VueJS + Firebase",
  body: "With VueJS+Firebase, I can take over the worlddd! Here's how I'll do it..."
}
```

Using the `ListOfThoughts.vue` component, we can render our `thoughts` to our template like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="list-of-thoughts">
      <ThoughtItem v-for="thought in thoughts" :thought="thought" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from './../firebase'
import ThoughtItem from './ThoughtItem.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    ThoughtItem
  },
  data () {
    return {
      thoughts: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    const thoughtsRef = firebase.database().ref().child('thoughts');
    thoughtsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      this.thoughts = snapshot.val();
    }, errorObject => {
      console.log('Error retrieving thoughts: ' + errorObject.code);
    })

  }
}
</script>
```

Notice that we are using the `ThoughtItem` component which looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="thought">
    <h1>{{thought.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{thought.body}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from './firebase'
export default {
  props: ['thought'],
  methods: {
    getThoughtKey() {
      // How can we access the Key of this particular `thought` here?
      // I need the key value to access the database object. Like this:
     firebase.database().ref().child(key);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

(Please check out the comments)

I am hoping to access the Key of this `thought` object so that I may update it. The object being passed down to the `ThoughtItem` component does not include the key. If we log the `thought` object which is passed as prop to the `ThoughtItem` component, it looks like this:

[image: Notice that there is no key property here]

In order to run further CRUD operations on this `thought` object, we need its key. How can we access its key from this child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your 'thoughts' object from the parent component contains the keys, and so looks like this:

```
thoughts: {
    key1: {
        title: title1,
        body: body1
    },
    key2: {
        title: title2,
        body: body2
    }
}
```

At least, this is how setting `this.thoughts = snap.val()` works when I tested.

When iterating through an object in Vue, you have access to the key of the item you are iterating, like this: `v-for="(thing,k) in myObject`. Now you can use `k` anywhere in the item to get the key. In your case, I would try

```
<ThoughtItem v-for="(thought,thoughtKey) in thoughts" :thought="thought" :thoughtKey="thoughtKey" />
```

Then you can accept `thoughtKey` as a prop in the child component and use it as you wish. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Firebase, but assuming your "thoughts" array is an array of Firebase objects (or references), you probably just have to use this.thought.key in your method.

```
getThoughtKey() {
 firebase.database().ref().child(this.thought.key);
}
```

Comment: The key is not passed down to the child component. Please see updated question for screenshot of the `thought` object as a prop.